# Raspberry Pi 4 Bluetooth Weak Range

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, home-assistant

**Context:**

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 sitting directly next to my iPhone.  I have a bluetooth multisensor ~3 rooms away that I am able to connect to from my phone but I cannot reach it from my Raspberry Pi (verified via `bluetoothctl`) for home automation purposes with Home Assistant.  When I bring the sensor in the same room as the iPhone and Raspberry Pi 4 I am able to receive data on both devices, but when I place it in its ideal location for my purposes, I am only able to reach it via iPhone.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way that I am able to extend the Raspberry Pi Bluetooth range via terminal in anyway?  I've already disabled WiFi in case that was causing any issues.
2. If not, is there a dongle I can add to the RP4 where I would be able to get an extended range?